# Why is inline-block pushing my div down:

Tags: html, css

When i use float: left. The DIVs both align perfectly at the top.
But when i am using display:inline-block it is pushing my div down. Why is this?

[image]

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="p1">
<p> test </p>
<p> test </p>
<p> test </p>
<p> test </p>
</div>
<div id="img1"> img </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my test.css:

```
#p1{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

#img1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.therockstargame.com/z_user_uploads/artwork/single/125_53470.jpg");
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align` property to align `inline-block` elements.

Here you can use `vertical-align: top;` to `#img1` for align perfectly at the top.

**Here is the working Snippet.**

```css
#p1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

#img1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.therockstargame.com/z_user_uploads/artwork/single/125_53470.jpg");
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="p1">
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
    <p> test </p>
  </div>
  <div id="img1"> img </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the snippet below, I've modified your code using the `vertical-align` property of the `inline-block` elements. This allows you to control their vertical alignment using `top`, `middle`, or `bottom` as possible values. More info and values are explained in [this great overview on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/).

```css
#p1{

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

#img1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.therockstargame.com/z_user_uploads/artwork/single/125_53470.jpg");
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 150px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div id="p1">
<p> test </p>
<p> test </p>
<p> test </p>
<p> test </p>
</div>
<div id="img1"> img </div>
```